# Can protocol buffers be used cross language

Tags: java, c#, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

Im reading up on protocol buffers. Can a serialized class created in C# be consumed Java. So for arguments sake, I want to make use of WebAPI (C#) and return various serialized classes depending on actions chosen. Can the serialized results be read from Java?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the serialized data is language-independent.

Comment: So in that case can you perhaps point me to an example of this perhaps a webpage or ebook reference?